Path.GetFullPath in MSBuild not working. What am I doing wrong?
I have several different automations in my solution.
Many of them uses [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath to help avoid missing files and the like.
However, Recently I added another project, but for some reason the GetFullPath is not working.
What am I doing wrong?
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <HelpPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(ProjectDir)..\..\User Guide')</HelpPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="HelpPath=$(HelpPath)" />
</Target>

The output of the MSBuild target above
2>HelpPath=$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(ProjectDir)..\..\User Guide')


You are missing a second closing brace ')' here to make it work:
    <PropertyGroup>
        <HelpPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(ProjectDir)..\..\User Guide'))</HelpPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

